How to correctly add background or big images to Android Studio for Views?
For example I have .jpg 4k image that I want to set as background, or other resolution .jpg/.png that I want to add somewhere on the screen (for example character that goes out from View). How should I add such images correctly to Android Studio, so it doesn't take a lot of memory and scales correctly on every device? I read about mdpi, hdpi, etc., but for real I didn't understand how I should make all of that from one image and what resolution for each density I should make for background or other image size for View. Can someone fully and in ditail explain how to do that?

You should place your image resources in res/drawable-nodpi so they will be used for any density.
Be sure the resources appear only in that directory otherwise the dpi-specific will be used.
When you import the resource in android studio select "no density".
